# customize cursor in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, cursor

How can I customize implict cursor to scan remote query (dblink) with similar name and identical structure (with similar filed name)?

I try this procedure code but I have this errors:

- line: 9, column: 38, error: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: tabella o vista
  inesistente
- line: 15, column: 41, error: PLS-00364: uso della variabile di indice
  loop 'C1' non valido

```
create table t1@DBLINK (
    id number,
    f1 varchar2(100),
    f2 varchar2(100),
    f3 varchar2(100),
    f4 varchar2(100)
);

insert into t1@DBLINK values (1,'t1 r1 f1','t1 r1 f2','t1 r1 f3','t1 r1 f4');
insert into t1@DBLINK values (2,'t1 r2 f1','t1 r2 f2','t1 r2 f3','t1 r2 f4');

create table t2@DBLINK (
    id number,
    f1 varchar2(100),
    f2 varchar2(100),
    f3 varchar2(100),
    f4 varchar2(100)
);

insert into t2@DBLINK values (1,'t2 r1 f1','t2 r1 f2','t2 r1 f3','t2 r1 f4');
insert into t2@DBLINK values (2,'t2 r2 f1','t2 r2 f2','t2 r2 f3','t2 r2 f4');

 1 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test AS
 2    nt varchar2(10);
 3    nf varchar2(10);
 4    js varchar2(400);
 5 BEGIN
 6     FOR n0 IN 1..2
 7         LOOP
 8             nt := 't' || n0 || '@DBLINK'; -- table name
 9             FOR c1 IN (SELECT * FROM nt)
10                 LOOP
11                     js := null;
12                     FOR n1 IN 1..4
13                         LOOP
14                             nf := 'f' || n1; -- field name
15                             js := js || c1.nf;
16                         END LOOP;
17                     dbms_output.put_line(js);
18                 END LOOP;
19         END LOOP;
20 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
21     NULL
22 END;
```

Comment: If you want the table name to be dynamic, you'd need to use dynamic SQL.  That's not going to work with an implicit cursor.  It isn't obvious from your question whether a solution with an explicit cursor is acceptable.  Having multiple similarly named and identically structured tables almost certainly indicates a problem with your data model that ought to be fixed by fixing the data model rather than writing dynamic SQL.  You could create a view that did a `union all` between the two tables but I'm guessing that isn't acceptable to you.

Comment: My problem is that the server I can only create queries on is an Oracle 11 server on which I can no longer do blob field reads (from my Oracle 18 server). So I created a series of queries that allow me through the DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR statement to fetch parts of the blobs and with 10 queries I can capture 99% of the registered blob data. These 10 queries have similar names and the same structure with 100 similarly named fields. I would like to create a routine that allows me not to write a procedure in full for rebuilding the blob.

Comment: I've not tried reading a `blob` over a database link from an old version of Oracle.  It sounds like you could just `create view myview as select * from v1 union all select * from v2 union all ...` and then use the new view.  Or just query the table and write a loop that makes various `dbms_lob.read` calls (that makes much more sense than `dbms_lob.substr` for reading `blob` data).